# Why I'm getting exceptions with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto and H2, but with PostgreSQL it works?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

I have remade my persistence config from Postgres only to multiple DB config by spring profiles. And I faced with this problem. I can't create H2 DB with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto and I'm getting this exception. With Postgres configuration everything is fine.

I have tried HSQLDB just as a test. But it still causes a DDL exception.

Persistence Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.beginnercourse.softcomputer")
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-postgres.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-h2.properties"})
//@NoArgsConstructor
//@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("postgres")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.connection_url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.username")));
        dataSource.setPassword(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.postgres.password")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("postgres")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean postgresSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(postgresDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"com.beginnercourse.softcomputer"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(postgresAdditionalProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties postgresAdditionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.hbm2ddl.auto")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.dialect")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.show_sql")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.postgres.default_schema")));
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache")));
//        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache")));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("oracle")
    public DataSource oracleDataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
    }


    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean testSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource ) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
//        postgresSessionFactory.setDataSource(postgresDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"com.beginnercourse.softcomputer"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(testAdditionalProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("test")
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.h2.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.h2.connection_url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.h2.username")));
        dataSource.setPassword(requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("jdbc.h2.password")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties testAdditionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.h2.hbm2ddl.auto")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.h2.dialect")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("hibernate.h2.show_sql")));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

persistence-h2.properties

```
jdbc.h2.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.h2.connection_url=jdbc:h2:mem:e-commerce
jdbc.h2.username=sa
jdbc.h2.password=sa

hibernate.h2.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.h2.show_sql=false
hibernate.h2.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Stacktrace(I had to shorten it):

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table order (id bigint generated by default as identity, placing_date date, status integer, customer_id bigint, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ORDER[*] (ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, PLACING_DATE DATE, STATUS INTEGER, CUSTOMER_ID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table order (id bigint generated by default as identity, placing_date date, status integer, customer_id bigint, primary key (id)) [42001-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    .
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE ORDER_ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT FKT6WV8M7ESHKSP5KP8W4B2D1DM FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDER[*] "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table order_item add constraint FKt6wv8m7eshksp5kp8w4b2d1dm foreign key (order_id) references order [42001-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:4530) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:4491) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]

2019-07-10 14:05:30 WARN  ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:27 - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table technologist add constraint FKjw43e4g7i69l0a2hb4mr0q10 foreign key (order_item_id) references order" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table technologist add constraint FKjw43e4g7i69l0a2hb4mr0q10 foreign key (order_item_id) references order" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE TECHNOLOGIST ADD CONSTRAINT FKJW43E4G7I69L0A2HB4MR0Q10 FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ITEM_ID) REFERENCES ORDER[*] "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table technologist add constraint FKjw43e4g7i69l0a2hb4mr0q10 foreign key (order_item_id) references order [42001-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:4530) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:4491) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseReferences(Parser.java:7749) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlterTableAddConstraintIf(Parser.java:7723) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlterTable(Parser.java:7204) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlter(Parser.java:6546) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:828) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:788) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:760) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:683) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:565) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1292) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:217) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
    ... 102 more
```

Has anyone else come across something similar?

Comment: `create table order (.....)` would not work in Postgres either

Comment: I just tested with Postgres, to be sure, and everything seems fine.

Comment: Then your obfuscation layer quotes that table name because `order` is a reserved keyword which can not be used like that. `create table "order" (..:)` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because your table name **"ORDER"** is a reserved SQL name. I would suggest avoiding this.
But if you still need it, take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases, specifically the `globally_quoted_identifiers` attribute.

Comment: Property hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers helped. Thank you.

Comment: Was facing same issue and It is very easy to miss this simple thing and then waste couple of hour scratching head, thanks a lot.